# MSM "You are not authorized to access this page" error

Tags: multi-site-manager

I'm having problems with an MSM install into an existing site (EE 2.9 / MSM 2.1.7) where non super admins can't switch to the added sites.

The links in the site switching dropdown look like `admin.php?/cp/sites&site_id=1&page=XXX` and `admin.php?/cp/sites&site_id=2&page=XXX` and when you click on them as a super admin you get redirected to whatever page you're on. But when logged in as a non-super admin you actually end up on `admin.php?/cp/sites&site_id=2&page=XXX` which is where the error message appears.

I've changed `cp_session_type` to cookies only and I've checked that the member group has the necessary privileges.

What else should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `/system/expressionengine/libraries/Sites.php` is unique to each MSM installation and needs to be downloaded from your account for the licence # it's associated with. You can't just copy a previously downloaded version of MSM over.

Answer (score 0):

Member group settings are unique per site.  Make sure that group has access to the control panel for the sites you wish them to have access on.

Comment: Just double checked again and yes, the member group does have CP access for both sites.